# AngularJS - Module config function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In [this example](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services):

```
angular.module('myModule', [], function($provide) {
  $provide.factory('serviceId', function() {
    var shinyNewServiceInstance;
    //factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
    return shinyNewServiceInstance;
  });
});
```

We have a function provided to `angular.module()`, that takes `$provide` argument.

1. If this gets minified, won't it break?  If I replace `$provide` with any other argument name (`$zprovide`), it can't find the provider.
2. Neither of these seem to work:

**`['$provide'], function($zprovide){}`**

```
angular.module('myModule', ['$provide'], function($zprovide) {
  $zprovide.factory('serviceId', function() {
    var shinyNewServiceInstance;
    //factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
    return shinyNewServiceInstance;
  });
});
```

**`['$provide', function($zprovide){}]`**

```
angular.module('myModule', ['$provide', function($zprovide) {
  $zprovide.factory('serviceId', function() {
    var shinyNewServiceInstance;
    //factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
    return shinyNewServiceInstance;
  });
}]);
```

It appears that the dependency injection system for the `angular.module()` function is different from the other services.  I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third "config function" parameter to the angular.module function is the same as calling module('myModule', []).config().  You should use that syntax if you want to pass dependencies.

```
angular.module('myModule', []).config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
  $provide.factory('serviceId', function () {
    var shinyNewServiceInstance;
    //factory function body that constructs shinyNewServiceInstance
    return shinyNewServiceInstance;
  });
}]);
```